# My co-worker left without me

Tags: relationships

Earlier today me and my coworker (whom I considered my supervisor as I'm relatively new to this workplace) went to attain a seminar related to our work. We sat separately as she came to the place late, but we got to talk during the break.

Our home is quite close so after the siminar I looked for her to tag along. I could't find her however, and waited for another 10 minutes. Then I made a call. It turned out she had other business and left early.

I felt a bit at a loss and insulted that she left without a word.
Do you think it's weird to expect your coworker to inform you if they are leaving? We are quite close and I consider her highly, but maybe to her I'm just an acquaintance? Maybe I am the weird one. What do you think?

---

Edited
Op here. You guys are right. I really do expect too much from her. It just my wishful thinking, I guess?. Thank you for setting it straight.

Comment: I think you're making a mountain out of a molehill.

Comment: You mentioned  **We are quite close** , But it seems you are not. Either she is not close or your expectations are high. it may be this is her nature.

Comment: You are overthinking this. You are only work colleagues. Whether she 'should' have informed you is a matter of opinion. Obviously her opinion is 'no' and yours seems to be 'yes'.

Comment: This is likely to be highly opinion based.  Some will say it's fine, others will not.  Either way, we have no way of knowing what she is thinking.  You will have to take that up with her.

Comment: Well, as long as it's no more worktime, she is perfectly entitled to whatever she wants. Even if she is your friend furing worktime.

Comment: Op here. You guys are right. I really do expect too much from her. It just my wishful thinking. Thank you for setting it straight.

Comment: Soliciting opinions is not a good fit for a Q&A site, we prefer questions that can have "correct" answers or can be answered generally and from experience. (Voted to close)

Comment: If you didn't ride together to get there, or sit together once there, or change seats after break so could sit together, then you probably weren't there "together". No reason should ride back to work together.

Answer (score 11):

Personally I would think there is no obligation for her to always inform you if she is leaving. Well, she might have something urgent that she forgets to inform you, or just want to have some privacy.

Take it easy dude, you are not her mother :)

Answer (score 4):

You don't sound upset that a *co-worker* snubbed you, you sound upset that a *friend* snubbed you.  It sounds like there is a crossing of the line between co-worker and friend, and this will be far more complicated if work-related issues arise.  IMHO, it can be fine to be friends with co-workers, although that obviously depends on the situation, and the burden is on the friendship to address business separately, not the other way around.

This is a friendship issue, not a work one. You should work hard to keep it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You're not the strange one here. Typically students and junior workers come to depend on their Mentor or Teacher. So it's not strange that you would feel this way, but at the same time you should understand that unless you specifically asked her for time together then there is no expectation for her to wait around for you.

This goes both ways too, it's not an expectation for you to wait around either. If you're lonely then it's time to make more friends - in your case make yourself more sociable to other coworkers and you can find peers to grow with on a professional and social level.